# Access denied with IE's XDomainRequest open("get",url)

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

IE suddenly started throwing this "Access is denied" error with XDomainRequest and I can't figure out what the hell is going on. Here's what I have:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
    // Use Microsoft XDR
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest(),
        url = 'http://someurl.com/x=1&y=2';

    xdr.open("get", url);
    xdr.onload = function () {
        doTheThing();
    };
    xdr.onprogress = function(){ };
    xdr.ontimeout = function(){ };
    xdr.onerror = function () { };
    setTimeout(function(){
        xdr.send();
    }, 0);
```

}

The error goes with the xdr.open("get",url), the weird thing is that this code was working fine and this solution is used everywhere I searched.

Comment: A bit unrelated: $.browser is removed in the latest versions of jQuery

Comment: Have you verified the remote server is still setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ? Looked in the IE console for error details?

Comment: @JanSommer I know, but this was a project set a time ago, that's why I was so surprised to see this error happening.

Comment: @AlexK. no details beside the "Access Denied" thing :( the server is ok, no changes since forever...

Answer (score 2):

There are restrictions in using XDomainRequest. If your page happens to be in https and your target is http, then you will get this error.

Take note that requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page. This restriction deliberately prevents HTTPS pages from making XDomainRequests for HTTP-based resources

More details can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx